# Inject Underscore in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Try to inject underscore but every time  its give me error 
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module underscore due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'underscore' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Here my code

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic','ui.filters','ui','ui.router','app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives','underscore'])
```

Already install form bower

```
<script src="lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-underscore-module/angular-underscore-module.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: No need to inject undersocre to your app module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no need to inject underscore to your app module, after you point out underscore js file in index page you can just use underscore features in your code.